# Python BeautifulSoup CSS Selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have code similar to this, repeated X times

```
<div class="ABC">     
    <div class="DEF"> 
        <span class="GHI">{TEXT 1}</span>
        <a href="#"><span class="{CLASS}">{TEXT 2}</span> {TEXT 3}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="DEF"> 
        <span class="GHI">{TEXT 1}</span>
        <a href="#"><span class="{CLASS}">{TEXT 2}</span> {TEXT 3}</a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="XYZ">     
    <div class="DEF"> 
        <span class="GHI">{TEXT 1}</span>
        <a href="#"><span class="{CLASS}">{TEXT 2}</span> {TEXT 3}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="DEF"> 
        <span class="GHI">{TEXT 1}</span>
        <a href="#"><span class="{CLASS}">{TEXT 2}</span> {TEXT 3}</a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

How would I extract each {TEXT 3} only where parent class is ABC? I have a solution where I prettify it and get the line number but was wondering if there was a neater way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
abc = soup.find('div', class_='ABC').find_all("div")
for div in abc:
    t3 = div.find('a').contents[1].strip()
    print (t3)
```

Output: `>>>{TEXT_3}` * 2

Comment: I need {TEXT 3}